# Where to find log4j.properties file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

In many anwers on this site related to `log4j` facilities, the answer says "edit your `log4j.properties` file".

Where can I find this file on disk in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You can't find it unless you've created it.

In a Java Project, it usually goes in a resources folder, e.g. src/main/resources in a maven-based setup. Create a log4j.properties or log4j.xml and it will automatically be picked up by all loggers from classes in that project.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sean's answer you can also put the log4j file somewhere else and let log4j know where it is by passing -Dlog4j.configuration= in the VM args.